# Eloquent ORM not throwing error

Tags: php, codeigniter, eloquent

I recently integrated eloquent with my codeigniter application via composer and things have worked great. The only issue I have is that when I try to do complicated relationships, like a belongsToMany or a hasManyThrough, I just get nothing back with no error code.

I'm loading: "illuminate/database": "4.0.*"

via composer. Is there something else I need to load to view or handle the errors?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: When I run a query with a ->with('') and then run a toSql, nothing is even returning. I have no idea why I'm not getting any output when I set it up and I'm not able to get any info on the query I'm expecting.

Comment: Did you check your...wait for it... PHP error logs??

Comment: Let me check... yes I did... dary.....

Comment: You should follow that with some contents of the error logs, or lack thereof. Best thing you can do is run a `tail -f` of the error logs and try reloading the page. `xdebug` could also be your friend if you don't want to spend so much time guessing

Comment: I haven't had any errors in my error log at all when I tail logfile. I just tested my controller and the script is getting killed when I make the eloquent call with eagerloading of the hasManyThrough relationship. Tried adding the php error settings to dispaly all errors and still nothing.